# Prove convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

Help please to prove the convergence: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}-n\cos\frac1n\right)\cos \frac{\pi n(n-1)}2$$

It can be proved with Dirichlet's test, but there are come problems with $$\left(\frac{1}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}-n\cos\frac1n\right)$$ monotone. Other steps in this way are clear. Or I should use another test?

Comment: Do you know Taylor series?

Comment: Yes, what you want to decompose?

Comment: Third installment of the same question. Did you warn the potential answerers that their answers will disappear when you will delete this and switch to the fourth installment?

Comment: This is the last question, sorry :) Older installments were a bit different and they didn't answer the question. I hope it will.

Comment: "Older installments were a bit different and they didn't answer the question" Seriously? How were they different? And why would you avoid deleting the answers you receive this time since you already did exactly this, twice?

Comment: Other posts were not mine and respectively I did not delete their answers, maybe I didn't understand your last message. I just saw similar posts.

Comment: Yes, yes, we know... "Yury Gladkikh, Member since today". :-)

Comment: I registered here to ask this question, nothing else. And nothing to discuss here too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\frac{1}{n}=x$.

Hence,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}-n\cos\frac1n\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin{x}}-\frac{\cos{x}}{x}\right)=$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}\sin2x}{x\sin{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos2x}{\sin{x}+x\cos{x}}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2\sin^2x}{x\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}+\cos{x}\right)}=0.$$

Since with $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos\frac{\pi n(n-1)}{2}$$ you know what to do, by the Dirichlet's Test we'll done if we'll prove that $a_{n+1}\leq a_{n}$, where
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}-n\cos\frac1n$$ or $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}f'(x)>0$, where
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin{x}}-\frac{\cos{x}}{x},$$
which is easy.

Indeed, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left(-\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^2x}-\frac{-x\sin{x}-\cos{x}}{x^2}\right)=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}+\frac{\cos x(\sin^2x-x^2)}{x^2\sin^2x}\right)=$$
$$=1+\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin{x}-x}{x^3}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}+1}{\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}}=$$
$$=1+2\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\cos{x}-1}{3x^2}=1-\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x^2}{4}}=\frac{2}{3}>0$$
and we are done!

Comment: We need monotone to use Dirichlet, this is problem :(

Comment: @Yury Gladkikh Our problem is solved. Now  tell  something about Dirichlet  and we are done!

Comment: I need to prove convergence of the series, not sequence(

Comment: So, for x this function increases in zero, and for n it will decrease in +inf, is it right?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes,  Yury, of course! You are welcome!